# SPARQL - Extract Label from entity URI

Tags: sql, database, sparql, wikidata

I'm trying to extract a list of diseases that have symptoms from [Wikidata](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata:Main_Page).

The thing is, when I query I get a list of entity URIs, not a list of labels, for the **Symptoms** column.

My query, tested on [here](https://query.wikidata.org) :

```
SELECT ?disease ?diseaseLabel (GROUP_CONCAT(?symptoms; SEPARATOR = ", ") AS ?Symptoms) 

WHERE {
  ?disease wdt:P31 wd:Q12136.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
  OPTIONAL { ?disease wdt:P780 ?symptoms. }
  FILTER(EXISTS { ?disease wdt:P780+ ?symptom. })
}

GROUP BY ?disease ?diseaseLabel
```

Which gives the following result :

[image]

For example , at the disease **measles** ,what I want to select for the Symptoms column is : **fever, cough, runny nose, maculopapular rash, lymphadenopathy, anorexia, diarrhea..**

Which are the exact labels for the URIs in the Symptom column for the particular disease.

Any help/hint and suggestions are welcomed , thank you !

Comment: Use the standard SPARQL way and get the `rdfs:label`: `OPTIONAL { 
    ?disease wdt:P780 ?symptoms. 
    ?symptoms rdfs:label ?symptomsLabel 
    FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?symptomsLabel), 'en'))
  }`

Comment: Oh, nicely done indeed. Cheers!